# Angular unit tests not passing - Unusual phantomjs error

Tags: angular, unit-testing, phantomjs, karma-runner

I run `ng test` to run my 3 unit tests **that are hardcoded to pass**, for example:

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    // const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    // const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    // expect(app).toBeTruthy();

    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
```

However, I am getting this odd error:

```
12 04 2019 16:38:11.231:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
12 04 2019 16:38:11.256:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS                                                             12 04 2019 16:38:19.761:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket nXFNY5PRUCvs5FtgAAAA with id 70621517
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) AppComponent should create the app FAILED
        parse
        then
        _parseTemplate
        _compileTemplate
        forEach
        _compileComponents
        _compileModuleAndAllComponents
        compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync
        compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync
        compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync
        compileComponents
        compileComponents
        invoke
        onInvoke
        onInvoke
        invoke
        runGuarded
        runInTestZone
        invoke
        onInvoke
        invoke
        run
        runInTestZone
        execute
        execute
        invokeTask
        runTask
        drainMicroTaskQueue
        parse
        then
        _parseTemplate
        _compileTemplate
        forEach
        _compileComponents
        _compileModuleAndAllComponents
        compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync
        compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync
        compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync
        _initIfNeeded
        createComponent
        createComponent
        invoke
        onInvoke
        invoke
        run
        runInTestZone
```

That's all the error stack says.

Comment: could you provide your `beforeEach` content ?

Comment: @Andrei Updated, please check.

Comment: I think something from AppComponent template is missing. you should add those children components into declarations section

Comment: @Andrei I'm not sure what else I would add.

Comment: @Andrei Actually you're right, I had to add some missing components. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I had imported `import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';` in my `app.component.ts` file and used it there, so I also had to import it into my `.spec.ts` file and declare it as a schema:

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA // needed to add this
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```